# Is there a way to generate this class of bivariate distributions from two uniform random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I need to generate a pair of random variables $U,V$ with distribution
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v)\propto(u+v)^{-4}
$$
in $u,v\in[1,L]$ with $L>1$. I managed to invert the CDF of the marginal distribution for one of the RVs but this already requires finding the root of
a fourth order polynomial.

I'm not familiar at all with the theory of generating random variables, so maybe this is the best I can hope for, but to the untrained eye this looks so "simple" that I would have expected a simple solution method to get $U$ and $V$ from a bunch of uniform random variables. I thought I'd post it here in the hope that someone with a good eye for these things might recognize a simple approach.

Comment: Is $L$ large or small? If $L$ is large, then there is a good algorithm. A small $L$ is a different story...

Comment: Small. I.e. $L<10$. But do share the good algorithm for large $L$ if you don't mind!

Comment: the power $-4$ makes $L\ge 5$ or even $L\ge 4$ already large. Then I'll give both, but small $L$ will take some more time.

Comment: Any problems with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not go too deeply into details and refer to Luc Devroye's book *Non-uniform random variate generation* for more ideas.

Sorry for changing your notation: $U$ is always a uniform variable for me. So let $U_1, U_2, \dots$ be uniform $[0,1]$ random variables. We want to generate $X_1$ and $X_2$ with density $$f_X(x_1,x_2) \propto (x_1+x_2)^{-4}\mathbf{1}_{[1,L]}(x_1)\mathbf{1}_{[1,L]}(x_2).$$ It is more convenient to consider $V_i = X_i-1,i=1,2,$ so that $$f_V(x_1,x_2)\propto (2+x_1+x_2)^{-4}\mathbf{1}_{[0,L-1]}(x_1)\mathbf{1}_{[0,L-1]}(x_2).$$
The main idea is that $V_1$ has a uniform distribution given $V_1+V_2$, and the latter has density $\propto x(2+x)^{-4}$ up to some point.

**Generating for large $L$**

1. Generate a random variable $V$ with density $\propto x(x+2)^{-4}$, $x\ge 0$. You can make this using some rejection algorithm, but it is better to observe that $V/(V+2)$ has density $\propto x(1-x)$, which is related to order statistics. Therefore,

   i. Generate $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$ and take the middle $U_{(2)}$ of them.

   ii. Set $V = 2U_{(2)}/(1-U_{(2)})$.
2. If $V>2L-2$, reject and go to 1.
3. Generate $U_4$ and set $V_1 = U_4 V$, $V_2 = (1-U_4) V$.
4. If $V_1> L - 1$ or $V_2 > L - 1$, reject both and go to 1.
5. Add $1$ to both $V_1$ and $V_2$ and output them.

Why does this work? Just assume for a moment that the rejection step 2 is not there. Then at st step 3 the random variables $V_1$ and $V_2$ have density $\propto (2+x_1+x_2)^{-4}\mathbf{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(x_1)\mathbf{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(x_2)$.

The rejection is equivalent to conditioning this to $[0,L-1]\times[0,L-1]$, which will get us what we need.

Note that the step 2 is not necessary at all: if $V>2L-2$, then it is going to be rejected anyway. So this is just for efficiency: we can drop such values before generating $U_4$ and making some operations.

The fact that $L$ is large will ensure that there are not too many iterations. In fact, for $L=4$ the probability of rejection is around $0.02$-$0.05$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, very interesting. When you say "observe that $V/(V+2)$ has density $\propto x(1−x)$", how did you make that observation? Is there some obvious trick? I went through the derivation to convince myself that this works but I certainly wouldn't have seen that by staring at the PDF for $V$! If you can point me to a relevant chapter in your reference on that, that'd be just as good.

Comment: Also, just to check: the rejection rate at step $(2)$ is the probability that $U_{(2)}>1-1/L$. With $U_{(2)} \sim Beta(2,2)$ this gives me about $0.16$ for $L=4$, higher than the number you quote. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @matimo2, I think you are right, the numbers I wrote were just a wild guess.

Comment: @matimo2, yes, I forgot to multiply by 6 when I was estimating that integral. So around one third of the values will be rejected, which is still acceptable. The idea I had for a small $L$ proved not very good because of the multiple $x$. There is also a rejection algorithm, but it's quite bad because of this multiple.